# How to make dateparser parse date relative to a given day

Tags: python-3.x, dateparser

I am using dateparser python's module to parse dates. How can I get dateparser to count not from the current date and time, but from the date I set, like `today = datetime(2021, 1, 1)`?

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/ "Stack Overflow") Please be aware this is not a code-writing or tutoring service. We can help solve specific, technical problems, not open-ended requests for code or advice. Please edit your question to show what you have tried so far, and what specific problem you need help with. See the [How To Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask "How To Ask a Good Question") page for details on how to best help us help you.

Comment: This is not a code-writing question. It's a reasonable question for people who is familiar with DateParser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `RELATIVE_BASE` in settings.

For example:

```
parse('tomorrow', settings={'RELATIVE_BASE': datetime.datetime(2020, 1, 1)})
```